Memory effective way to stream data from HttpResponseMessage to content in middleware
I'm trying to make a middleware that will request a specific information from a distant server, and I want to stream the content directly to the response content in my middleware.
I have code like this for now :
public class MonMiddleware(
    RequestDelegate next,
    HttpClient client)
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/media")
        {
            HttpResponseMessage? response = await client.GetAsync("https://corporatelorem.kovah.de/api/2");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString();
                context.Response.ContentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

                var writer = PipeWriter.Create(context.Response.Body);
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(writer.AsStream());
                await writer.CompleteAsync()

                return;
            }

            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return;
        }

        await next(context);
        // Do something with context near the end of the request
    }
}

However, it looks like the Content.CopyToAsync is reading the content and reseriliazing it into a stream...
How can I avoid any reading and just stream the data to the context.Response.Body?

You can avoid some of the code above my writing directly to HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter

Indeed, there's a PipeWriter directly setup for the body. But that doesn't get rid of allocations of the response.Content.CopyToAsync, or I'm missing something?

Use PipeWriter.CopyFromAsync()? context.Response.BodyWriter.CopyFromAsync(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())?

ReadAsStreamAsync() will serialize the content and put it into a stream : ReadAsStreamAsync. Moreover, CopyFromAsync is protected internal

That gives you a stream that is a "pointer" to the content over the wire from the remote HTTP source - it won't necessarily greedily read it (i.e. buffer it). Use a tool like BenchmarkDotNet to compare it to your current approach and see if it is really consuming the content or not, or whether it's just being copied directly into the PipeWriter for you (which is what you want).

My goal is to avoid the entire stream content to be allocated in memory, and it appears that neither approach allow me to do that for now. If you debug and put a breakpoint, you will see that the stream is already with the size of the response

Try using the option that tells HttpClient to only receive the headers and not consume the body: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-httpcompletionoption-responseheadersread-to-improve-httpclient-performance-dotnet

Good advice! It seems to do the job, I'll investigate more, thanks for that
